# Are Time Machine backups encrypted?

Tags: macos, macbook, time-machine

I have snow leopard + pgp 10.0 with FDE

Will my backups on the time machine be encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not, but there are [steps around this](http://destefano.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/time-machine-encryption/).

Comment: After reading that link I fail to see how it contains any information about how to encrypt Time Machine backups and I wish I hadn't voted +1

Comment: The linked article mentions, in turn, this one: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2007111404402514 which I think is relevant.